# sublime phpfmt stopped working missing php-cs-fixer

Tags: sublimetext3

I have been using the sublime-phpfmt plugin without issue for a while now but have been getting the following error:

`engine file is missing: /Users/iMac/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/phpfmt/php-cs-fixer`

I installed php-cs-fixer globally and have put the php-cs-fixer.phar file into the local directory as instructed in the readme, but it's still coming up like this. The output of the console is as follows:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'phpcs'`

I don't know anything about python, but is it looking for a different file or something?

**Edit**

It seems like there has been some argy-bargy with the plugin, details here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11896851 and https://github.com/nanch/sublime-phpfmt with the general consensus being to manually install the package and checkout an old commit like so:

1. Remove phpfmt from package control (if you installed it that way)
2. Clone https://github.com/nanch/sublime-phpfmt.git into your packages directory (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` on mac)
3. cd into `sublime-phpfmt` and `git checkout 6125cf9`

That worked for me, and it will also not auto-update (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Seems like `phpfmt` has gone commercial and requires you to purchase a license to use it: https://github.com/phpfmt/issues/issues/17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by downloading [php-cs-fixer.phar](http://get.sensiolabs.org/php-cs-fixer.phar) and creating link to it in /Packages/phpfmt/php-cs-fixer.

```
ln -s php-cs-fixer.phar ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/phpfmt/php-cs-fixer
```

Don't know what changed but this seems to work.

Comment: Ah great, thanks! I hadn't made the php-cs-fixer.phar file executable, that's why it wasn't working.

To be super verbose, this is what I did to fix it:

````composer global require fabpot/php-cs-fixer```` then

````ln -s /usr/bin/php-cs-fixer ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/phpfmt/php-cs-fixer````

I don't really like the change in format style though. Looking at the repo, the file fmt.phar was removed a couple of days ago.